Horizontal arrow between two vertical arrows
In tickzcd environment, I have the following commutative diagram:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{tikzcd}
X \arrow{r} \arrow[swap]{d}{f} & F(X) \arrow{d}{Ff} \\%
Y \arrow{r}& F(Y)
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}

Which is producing the picture:

I want to draw a dashed arrow between the verticle arrows of f and Ff in the middle. How to do this kind of stuff?

Please add what’s missing so it compiles … (1000+1st reminder)

Look in the manual for dashed. Find e.g. dashed arrows … https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd?lang=en

You can name the arrows.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{tikzcd}
X\mathstrut \arrow[r] \arrow[d,swap,"f"{name=L}] & F(X) \arrow[d,"Ff"{name=R}] \\
Y\mathstrut \arrow[r] & F(Y)
\arrow[dashed,from=L,to=R,shorten=3pt]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}

Avoid the complicated syntax of \arrow with several arguments; the syntax \arrow[<options>] is much more flexible.
I used \mathstrut in order to make the nodes equal in vertical size.


Here's a MWE that doesn't require the \arrow command and explicitly calls out the nodes to place the arrow.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (x) at (0, 2) {$X$};
        \node (y) at (0, 0) {$Y$};
        \node (Fx) at (2, 2) {$F(X)$};
        \node (Fy) at (2, 0) {$F(Y)$};
        \node (p1) at (0, 1) {};
        \node (p2) at (2, 1) {};

        \draw[->] (x) -- (y) node[midway, left] {$f$};
        \draw[->] (x) -- (Fx);
        \draw[->] (y) -- (Fy);
        \draw[->] (Fx) -- (Fy) node[midway, right] {$Ff$};
        \draw[->, dashed] (p1) -- (p2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Edit: Forgot to dash the arrow.
